# getPostMeta in Wordpress - unable to add calculation to a value

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to change the value of a getPostMeta value in Wordpress.

I want to add a percentage or specific amount to a value stored in a field that I am retrieving using getPostMeta() in Wordpress.  I have managed to do this with one field (the discounted price) using:

```
<?php getPostMeta('dprice') /100 * 120; ?> //this works and returns the discounted price with a percentage added to it
```

I am trying to do the same with another field (the main price) using:

```
<?php getPostMeta('price') /100 * 120; ?> //this returns 1.2
```

or

```
<?php getPostMeta('price') + 200; ?> //this returns 201
```

If i retrieve the price on it's own:

```
<?php getPostMeta('price');?> // it returns the proper amount - 1,295
```

I have put the full section of code below - can anyone tell me why these two similar fields are showing differently when I try to add to the amount stored in the field?

```
<?php $dlondonPrice = getPostMeta('dprice') / 100 * 120; ?>
<?php $londonPrice = getPostMeta('price') + 200 ?>
<?php $locationTest = trim($row[1]); ?>

    <?php if( $sale ) : ?>

      <?php if($locationTest == "London") : ?>

        <del class="oldprice">&pound;<?= is_numeric($londonPrice) ? number_format($londonPrice, 0, '.', ',') : $londonPrice; ?> </del><span>&pound;<?= is_numeric($dlondonPrice) ? number_format($dlondonPrice, 2, '.', ',') : $dlondonPrice; ?> +VAT</span>

      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php if($locationTest != "London") : ?>

          <del class="oldprice">&pound;<?= is_numeric($price) ? number_format($price, 0, '.', ',') : $price; ?> </del><span>&pound;<?= is_numeric($sale) ? number_format($sale, 2, '.', ',') : $sale; ?> +VAT</span>

      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php elseif ($locationTest =="London") : ?>

    &pound;<?= is_numeric($londonPrice) ? number_format($londonPrice, 2, '.', ',') : $londonPrice; ?>

        <?php else : ?>

        &pound;<?= is_numeric($price) ? number_format($price, 2, '.', ',') : $price; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What does your `getPostMeta` look like? The builtin function is get_postmeta, so I'm guessing your custom one does something special?

Comment: Hi, sorry I have been trying to track this down but I have not been able to (I didn't build the site - just trying to make a few changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is with "," decimal separator. By default your function can't parse float number and takes it whole part.
So, replace it with "." and it will work OK.
For example

```
<?php floatval(str_replace(",",".",getPostMeta('price'))) + 200; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this  I changed to <?php $londonPrice = floatval(str_replace(",",".",getPostMeta('price'))) + 200; ?> but it is still not working.

Comment: You have a space before ",". So try this floatval(str_replace(" ,",".",getPostMeta('price'))) as well

Comment: Please tell me what you get of you type just this:. echo str_replace(",",".",getPostMeta('price'));

Comment: Hi, this returns 1.295

Comment: i don't know what you are doing wrong - because you just confirmed that the code works. Anyway, as a last attempt try this, and make sure that you really applied this to the right place: echo floatval(str_replace(array(","," "),"",getPostMeta('price'))) + 200; //it should return 1495 and if so, it means that the problem has been resolved

Comment: thanks so much - working as it should now with your help.